# Why does Rust require Copy and Clone traits for simple enum

Tags: rust, enums

The following code will not compile unless `Copy` and `Clone` traits are derived in the enum. Why is this a requirement given that the enum is basically an `i8` and [according to the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#:%7E:text=All%20the%20integer%20types%2C%20such%20as%20u32), integers automatically implement the Copy trait? Related to this, since the size of `MyEnum` should be well known at compile time, shouldn't it go onto the stack? Doesn't the `Clone` trait imply that it goes on the heap?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(i8)]
enum MyEnum {
    Some1,
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyEnum::Some1;
    let y = x;
    println!("x={:?} y={:?}", x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Clone` has nothing to do with the heap. `Clone` does not imply heap-allocated for any type, be they `struct`s, `enum`s, and whether they have a `#[repr]` attribute or not. `Clone` is just a normal trait.

And traits aren't implemented automatically, ever, because when writing a library, this would be an implicit part of your public interface. That is, an type could be implicitly, and unexpectedly, `Clone` without the library author intending to make it `Clone`. This limits how the type could change in the future, and the library author might inadvertently break their public interface by changing the content of the type and losing that implicit trait implementation. Rust always prefers explicitness over hidden things.

Comment: *And traits aren't implemented automatically, ever* - Marker traits (`Send`, `Sync`, `Unpin`) are a notable exception to this.

Comment: I'm confused when you say `trains aren't implemented automatically, ever`. Doesn't https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#additional-implementors mean that `Clone` is automatically implemented for quite a few types?

Comment: @PaulGrinberg the implementations for those types are within the compiler. The clone trait is lang item, which means rustc is specifically aware of it, and so implementations more general then what's allowed within the rust language itself can be created.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg I meant for user defined types. All the types mentioned in the link above are special "built-in" types. And as mentioned in a previous comment, marker traits can be implemented automatically. But `Clone` isn't a marker trait, and while `Copy` is, what I said in my answer does apply to it. `Send`, `Sync` and `Unpin` however are traits which you usually want automatically, because if you don't, you probably already know you don't.